# Troubleshooting scheduled task permissions in Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I am having trouble with a scheduled task that launches a python script (via a batch file) which moves some files around my network. I am running Windows 10, and on a large enterprise network that authenticates using my domain/username.

When the scheduled task is set to "run whether or not the user is logged on", the python script is unable to access the source directory (a network drive), and throws a username/password error in my error log. The scheduled task runs the program correctly if set to "run only if user is logged on", or if the batch is run manually.

To address some of the solutions I have found to similar-sounding problems in the archives:

- I have already checked that all my network locations are explicit (\server\dir, not mapped letter drives) and that the script is using my username.
- For troubleshooting I have Python call several environmental variables from Windows and log them to a file, such as %USERNAME% and %USERPROFILE% - they are both correct, regardless of which way I am running the scheduled task, and so does not reflect my problem.
- I have also tried a variety of paths for the "Start in" optional argument in the scheduled task properties - C:/, C:/batch folder, etc. - no luck.

Using the Process Monitor tool, I have looked at the stack for the CreateFile operation that succeeds in one case and fails in the other - they appear identical. I assume there must be some earlier step where my computer checks for permissions, which will then cause my task to fail or succeed, but I cannot seem to figure out where.

Does anyone have any ideas? My head is pretty sore from banging against this wall for the last few days :) Thank you!

-MS

Comment: Have you checked to see that the user assigned to run the program has permission to the directories?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same user account (my primary one) in all cases. That reminds me: in the course of troubleshooting I also added explicit share permissions to each of the local directories (the directory with my batch file, the dir with my python script, and win32 just to be safe) for my domain user account. This should make sure it had all the local permission it needed, and addressed one of the suggestions I found in the forum.